# reading lines from file to make 2D dictionary [python]

Tags: python, database, dictionary

take a look at the following database.txt file:

```
donald
duck
123456
donald@duck.com
--------------------
suzy
giraffe
78910
suzy@giraffe.com
--------------------
```

i need to take that file create a 2D dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {
       'donald': {'fname': donald, 'lname': duck, 'phone': 123456, 'email': donald@duck.com}
       'suzy':   {'fname': suzy, 'lname': giraffe, 'phone': 78910, 'email': suzy@giraffe.com}
       }
```

the program should take the first name and create a key with it, and then take everything else, including the first name again, and create a second dictionary with other keys as an element to the key. when it reaches the "--------------------" it should restart this process. the goal is to be able to use the dictionary as such:

```
dict['donald']['phone'] = 123456
dict['suzy']['email'] = suzy@giraffe.com
```

i have this so far, i am taking everything from the file and placing it in an list after i remove the linebreak from the string.

```
fhandle = open(input("Enter the database filename: "), "r")
    lines = []
    with fhandle as insert:
        for line in insert:
            cleaned_line = line.replace("\n", "")
            lines.append(cleaned_line)
```

any ideas??

Comment: You really ought to look at `collections.namedtuple`.

Comment: reason i didnt use tuples is because this data has to be mutable -- i have to use dictionaries for this assignment anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with common string operations (**`split()`**, **`strip()`**, etc.):

```
with open('database.txt', 'r') as f:
    results = dict()

    for line in f.read().strip().split('--------------------'):
        if line.strip() != "":
            first_name, last_name, phone, email = line.strip().split('\n')
            results[first_name] = dict(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, phone=phone, email=email)

    print results
```

Other way of doing exactly the same but with **`list and dict comprehensions`**:

```
with open('database.txt', 'r') as f:
    results = {first_name:dict(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, phone=phone, email=email) for first_name, last_name, phone, email in [line.strip().split('\n') for line in f.read().split('--------------------') if line.strip() != ""]}
    print results
```

**Output is the same for both cases:**

```
{
    'donald': {
        'phone': '123456',
        'first_name': 'donald',
        'last_name': 'duck',
        'email': 'donald@duck.com'
    },
    'suzy': {
        'phone': '78910',
        'first_name': 'suzy',
        'last_name': 'giraffe',
        'email': 'suzy@giraffe.com'
    }
}
```

Comment: @udpcon np. Btw, why did you removed my answer as accepted?

Comment: must have been an accident, i'm new here so i wasn't quite sure what the check mark did. cheers

Comment: @udpcon the checkmark is to set an answer as the correct one for your question. There are also up-votes and down-votes that work like Facebook "likes". I'm glad my answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution I would do something like:

```
def parse_dict(name, lname, phone, email):
    return (name, {"lname": lname, "phone": phone, "email": email})


with open("test.data") as f:
    line_list = f.readlines()


data = {}
entry = []
for line in line_list:
    if not line.startswith("---"):
        entry.append(line.strip())
    else:
        # Send to process:
        name, record = parse_dict(*entry)
        data[name] = record
        # Reset entry:
        entry = []

print data, "\n"
print data["donald"], "\n"
print data["donald"]["email"], "\n"
```

Output:

```
{'donald': {'lname': 'duck', 'phone': '123456', 'email': 'donald@duck.com'}, 'suzy': {'lname': 'giraffe', 'phone': '78910', 'email': 'suzy@giraffe.com'}} 

{'lname': 'duck', 'phone': '123456', 'email': 'donald@duck.com'} 

donald@duck.com
```

Answer (score 1):

with dict comprehension:

```
keys = ['fname', 'lname', 'phone', 'email']

with open('database.txt', 'r') as stream:
    a = stream.read().split('--------------------\n')
    print({i.split('\n')[0]: dict(zip(keys, i.split('\n'))) for i in a})
```

output:

```
{
    "suzy": {
        "email": "suzy@giraffe.com", 
        "fname": "suzy", 
        "lname": "giraffe", 
        "phone": "78910"
        }, 
    "donald": {
        "email": "donald@duck.com", 
        "fname": "donald", 
        "lname": "duck", 
        "phone": "123456"
        }
}
```